# I want to set max value(with id and coming from ajax) into Html.EditorFor()

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

After I select from dropdown list, the value of stock is coming via ajax and I want to user can not write amount value bigger than that stock value. I can not add that max value to html.editorfor

Create.cshtml

```
         <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",min="1", max=$("#stock")} })
                </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#depotId').change(function () { sendDataByAjax(); });
    })

    function sendDataByAjax() 
        var materialId= $('#materialId option:selected').val();
        var depotId= $('#depotId option:selected').val();

        if (!materialId || !depoId) {
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetStock", "OutgoingProduct")",
            data: {
                'materialId': materialId,
                'depotId': depotId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#stock").html(data);

            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a proper way to set attribute value of an `<input>` element with just jQuery selector like `$("#stock")`. I think you should define the `EditorFor` helper without max value first:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", min="1" }})
```

Then handle `change` or `onchange` event from the dropdown in client-side to add or set `max` attribute to the `<input>` element generated by `EditorFor`:

```
$("#dropdownId").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    // other stuff

    // if the data comes as single value response, just set it to input element with 'prop()'
    $.get('@Url.Action("TargetActionName", "TargetControllerName")', { id: value }, function (data) {
       // set maximum value here
       $('#amount').prop('max', data); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not understand, how should I write "dropdownId"

Comment: The `dropdownId` is your DropDownList(For)'s element ID, you can find it by looking for `<select id="dropdownId" ...></select>`. You need to handle its `change` event in order to set other element's value from selected option value.